# Decoding url from json on Android

Tags: java, android

From a Rest API, I get json data in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "item": "tea",
        "price": "7.5",
        "image": "http:\/\/192.168.1.3\/CI\/images\/tea.jpg",
        "veg": "0",
        "category": "drinks"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "item": "coffee",
        "price": "10",
        "image": "http:\/\/192.168.1.3\/CI\/images\/coffee.jpg",
        "veg": "0",
        "category": "drinks"
    }
]
```

From the API I get Json as a string and it contains backslashes in front of url's forward slashes, which is according to the json encoding specification. And I am correctly able to json_decode and get url from php. In android I store the json string in a variable named "menu_json".

Then I am trying to parse and get the image url from it using the following code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
try{
    JSONObject menuApiObj = new JSONObject(menu_json);
    JSONArray menuObj = menuApiObj.getJSONArray("menu");
    for (int i = 0; i < menuObj.length(); i++){
        JSONObject row = menuObj.getJSONObject(i);
        rowString = row.getString("image");
        imageUrl = row.toString();
        Log.e("rowString", rowString);
        Log.e("imageUrl", imageUrl);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "item": "tea",
    "price": "7.5",
    "image": "tea.jpg",
    "veg": "0",
    "category": "drinks"
}
```

The image field is supposed to be:

```
http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/tea.jpg
```

But instead I get just:

```
tea.jpg
```

When json_decode the API response in PHP, I get the correctly decoded url. But in Android, I am not getting the correctly decoded url in image field.

Please help!

Here is the complete API response:

```
{"menu":[{"id":"1","item":"tea","price":"7.5","image":"tea.jpg","veg":"0","category":"drinks"},{"id":"2","item":"cofee","price":"10","image":"coffee.jpg","veg":"0","category":"drinks"},{"id":"3","item":"crispy chicken","price":"160","image":"crispy-chicken.jpg","veg":"0","category":"curries"}],"cat_wise":[{"category":"drinks","items":[{"id":"1","item":"tea","price":"7.5","image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.3\/CI\/images\/tea.jpg","veg":"0","category":"drinks"},{"id":"2","item":"cofee","price":"10","image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.3\/CI\/images\/coffee.jpg","veg":"0","category":"drinks"}]},{"category":"curries","items":[{"id":"3","item":"crispy chicken","price":"160","image":"http:\/\/192.168.1.3\/CI\/images\/crispy-chicken.jpg","veg":"0","category":"curries"}]},{"category":"main","items":[]}]}
```

Comment: Show you complete JSON data. What does `menuApiObj.getJSONArray("menu")` mean? There is no such array in the given JSON data,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what Json library you're using, but it looks like `org.json`. I thought your code looked sane, so I implemented it and do not see the output that you are seeing. My guess is that your input data isn't what you expect it to be.

```
final JSONArray menuObj = new JSONArray("[\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
        "        \"item\": \"tea\",\n" +
        "        \"price\": \"7.5\",\n" +
        "        \"image\": \"http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/tea.jpg\",\n" +
        "        \"veg\": \"0\",\n" +
        "        \"category\": \"drinks\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
        "        \"item\": \"coffee\",\n" +
        "        \"price\": \"10\",\n" +
        "        \"image\": \"http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/coffee.jpg\",\n" +
        "        \"veg\": \"0\",\n" +
        "        \"category\": \"drinks\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "]");
for (int i = 0; i < menuObj.length(); i++){
    final JSONObject row = menuObj.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("imageUrl: " +  row.getString("image"));
    System.out.println("rowString: " +  row);
}
```

Output:

> imageUrl: http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/tea.jpg rowString:
>   {"image":"http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/tea.jpg","item":"tea","price":"7.5","veg":"0","id":"1","category":"drinks"}
>   imageUrl: http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/coffee.jpg rowString:
>   {"image":"http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/coffee.jpg","item":"coffee","price":"10","veg":"0","id":"2","category":"drinks"}

Comment: Yes I am using org.json

Comment: Oh, I was getting frustrated and took a closer look at the API response. Looks like "menu" in json doesn't contain the full URL, only the "cat_wise" menu contains the full image URL. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To parse JSON Array :

```
    JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("menu");

     for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject innerjObject =jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       String image =innerjObject.getString("image");
       array_list.add(image);
     }
```

**output: http://192.168.1.3/CI/images/tea.jpg**

And to display this image to imageview use library :

**compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'**

using Loadimagview method of library load image in imageview